# Why doesn't Ruby's configure script detect my executables and header files?

Tags: compiling, ruby, configure

I'm trying to compile Ruby and really understanding what's going on while doing so. I've used and written `Makefiles` before, but not `autoconf`'s `configure.in` files, so maybe the result I'm getting is by design:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git
...
$ cd ruby
$ git clean -fdx
$ autoconf 
$ ./configure
...
checking for dot... no
checking for doxygen... no
checking for pkg-config... no
...
checking direct.h usability... no
checking direct.h presence... no
checking for direct.h... no
...
checking for daemon... (cached) no
```

However, all of these are at least installed:

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
$ doxygen --version
1.7.4
$ pkg-config --version
0.26
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate /direct.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-16-generic/include/config/pci/direct.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/include/config/pci/direct.h
$ daemon --version
daemon-0.6.4
```

I realize there might be different causes for each of these, but **why aren't they detected by the `configure` script?**

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with the latest patches.

```
$ uname -a
Linux username 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tried on another host. From `config.log`:

```
configure:6408: checking for dot
configure:6424: found /usr/bin/dot
configure:6438: result: no
configure:6445: checking for doxygen
configure:6461: found /usr/bin/doxygen
configure:6475: result: no
configure:6483: checking for pkg-config
configure:6504: found /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure:6530: result: no
```

What? They were found, but still no go?

```
configure:11880: checking direct.h usability
configure:11880: gcc -c  -O3 -ggdb    conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:135:20: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:11880: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
...
| #endif
| #include <direct.h>
configure:11880: result: no
configure:11880: checking direct.h presence
configure:11880: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:102:20: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:11880: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <direct.h>
configure:11880: result: no
configure:11880: checking for direct.h
configure:11880: result: no
```

Funky test script - Maybe it needs to be in a default path of some sort?

```
configure:15175: checking for daemon
configure:15175: result: no
```

Turns out this is not checking for an executable, but for a C function using [AC_CHECK_FUNCS](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Functions.html).

Comment: Look at the config.log file, might give some clues. (And remove config.cache if there was a stale one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know almost nothing about Ruby. I do, however know a fair amount about build
systems. I'm gonna go way out on a limb here and suggest **you've found a
bona-fide bug in the Ruby build system**.

Here's my reasoning:

1. I get the same result you do, on completely different
   systems (even Cygwin/Windows 7), both with the git repo
   you specify and the [stock Ruby 1.9 sources](http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p125.tar.gz)
2. The reason you see `found: /usr/bin/dot` in your `configure.log`
   is because it genuinely found it on the path. This is easy to see
   in the generated `configure` script, especially if you modify its
   first line to `#!/bin/sh -x` to get shell debug output:

   ```
   + test -z /bin
   + for ac_exec_ext in ''\'''\''' '$ac_executable_extensions'
   + test -f /bin/dot
   + test -x /bin/dot
   + ac_cv_prog_DOT=
   + printf '%s\n' 'configure:6424: found /bin/dot'
   + break 2
   + IFS='
   ```
3. The reason you see `result: no` is because, as you can see the
   snippet above, `ac_cv_prog_DOT` was set to empty string, and the
   following lines in configure simply reflect that missing value:

   ```
   + DOT=
   + test -n ''
   + printf '%s\n' 'configure:6438: result: no'
   + printf '%s\n' no
   no
   ```
4. The reason that was set to empty string is (and this is the crux
   of the matter) that `configure.in` specified empty string on line
   371:

   ```
   AC_CHECK_PROG(DOT, dot)
   AC_CHECK_PROG(DOXYGEN, doxygen)
   ```

   I belive that's a buggy invocation of the AC_CHECK_PROG macro, which
   the [GNU Autoconf docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Programs.html) specify takes **three** required arguments, not two:

   ```
   ― Macro: AC_CHECK_PROG (variable, prog-to-check-for, value-if-found, [value-if-not-found], [path = ‘$PATH’], [reject])

   Check whether program prog-to-check-for exists in path. If it
   is found, set variable to value-if-found, otherwise to
   value-if-not-found, if given. Always pass over reject (an
   absolute file name) even if it is the first found in the search
   path; in that case, set variable using the absolute file name
   of the prog-to-check-for found that is not reject. If variable
   was already set, do nothing. Calls AC_SUBST for variable. The
   result of this test can be overridden by setting the variable
   variable or the cache variable ac_cv_prog_variable.
   ```

   There's no default value. Leaving it off effectively means
   "if you find dot, set DOT to empty string"
5. I believe the reason this mistake was made was because the
   original definition for that line used a different macro,
   `AC_CHECK_TOOL`, that only takes two arguments.

   From  [checkin to svn.ruby-lang.org on Nov 11, 2010](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/configure.in?r1=29765&r2=29766&diff_format=l)

   [image: AC_CHECK_TOOL becomes AC_CHECK_PROG on]
6. It's possible this may have been busted for a while, and some
   ChangeLog comments seem to indicate that they've been having
   trouble with `DOXYGEN`, for example:

   ```
   Fri Mar 26 19:55:41 2010  Akinori MUSHA  <knu@iDaemons.org>

       * Makefile.in (DOXYGEN): Define a missing variable DOXYGEN.  Build
         has been failing when doxygen(1) is found by configure but the
         variable is not defined by the system and make(1) does not allow
         an empty command. ("@$(DOXYGEN)" was the cause)
   ```

Finally, it's possible I have this all wrong. But I'm pretty sure that
`configure` is finding those tools, and it has been instructed to
set the corresponding Makefile variables to empty string.

Curious to hear what others think of this analysis.

Comment: Excellent analysis. [Reported a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6316) for this.

Comment: It was a bug - Fixed in the repository. 1000 thanks, as we say at home.